# property not found after change to primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, el, propertynotfoundexception

I want to include a `prime-faces` component (`selectOneMenu`) in a `xhtml` page.
That component has originally been a normal jsf-component.
I included `prime-faces` with: `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"`.

After the change I get the following error when loading the page: `Property 'countryLocaleCodeChanged' not found on type logic.Internationalization`. 
 I already tried to do the request with `ajax`, with the same result (property not found error). 
 Why do I get this error?

I use:

- prime-faces 5.2

  jsf 2.2

  tomcat 8.0

Here are parts of the code:

.xhtml:

```
<h:form>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="languagemenu" 
        onchange="submit()"
        valueChangeListener="#{inter.countryLocaleCodeChanged}"
        value = "#{inter.localeCode}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{inter.countriesInMap}" /> 
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

.java:

```
public void countryLocaleCodeChanged(ValueChangeEvent e){
    String newLocaleValue = e.getNewValue().toString();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : countries.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getValue().toString().equals(newLocaleValue)){
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale((Locale)entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

.stacktrace:

```
javax.el.ELException: /pageHome.xhtml: Property 'countryLocaleCodeChanged' not found on type logic.Internationalization
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.AttributeInstruction.write(AttributeInstruction.java:94)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The culprit is not visible in the current question but send an asynchronous request, when an item (language) is changed in the given `<p:selectOneMenu>` and then make a redirect from the associated managed bean after the locale has successfully been set to the current HTTP session. This `onchange="submit()"` otherwise, sends an unwanted synchronous POST request.

Comment: @Tiny: no this is not related. As the error is in the facelets compiler and there is **no** PrimeFaces in the stacktrace **and** the error is in the  `UIInstructions`, it means that the EL is interpreted as a value expression. This all comes down to PrimeFaces not being available in the webapp at runtime,

Comment: At least that is what I have had before

Comment: I included the prime-face jar via eclipse configure-build-path ... is this not suficient?

Comment: Look for that JAR into the deployed WAR whether it is available there or not. Stop and start the server, clean & build / deploy the application all over again from scratch, if not.

Comment: that was right! The answer could be found in the 'duplicated' question!